# Scanf is not working in C

Tags: c, character, scanf

I am trying to work out why the second scanf is not working for me. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     char n;int p;
     printf("Enter the number: ");
     scanf("%d",&p);
     if(p==1) {
          printf("Enter a character: ");
          scanf("%c",&n);
     }
}
```

In this program the second `scanf("%c",&n)` is not working. What am I doing wrong? The output of above program is:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a charter:
```

It is coming out of compiler.

Comment: When the second colon appears you're supposed to enter something. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the previous `scanf()` left a newline in the input buffer. A simple fix to tell scanf to ignore all the whitespaces:

```
scanf(" %c",&n); //Note the space before %c
```

Any whitespace directive ( space, `\n` etc) in the format string tells scanf ignore any number of whitespaces in the input.

From [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) manual:

> ```
>    A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline,
>           etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of
>           white space, including none, in the input.
> ```

Comment: Dude thank for that but what is the space doing there ?

Comment: A whitespace in the format string means `scanf()` will ignore all whitespaces in the input. You can use any whitespace character for the same effect, not necessarily *space*. There are other ways to achieve the same such as reading all chars from stdin using `getchar()` in a loop. My general suggestion is to avoid `scanf()` whenever possible. Instead use `fgets()` to read a line and use `sscanf()` to parse the line as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The previous `scanf()` leaves a trailing newline character `\n`. Eat it by doing

```
scanf(" %c",&n);
```

Comment: Dude that was awesome thank for that. But how is that space is working dude ?

Comment: @RamanaUday It tells the `scanf()` to ignore all white spaces.