# In while loop char doesn't show output as i want

Tags: c, while-loop, char

I just don't understand where is the wrong? when I taking the input value without Y or y then output shows two times then I can again take input but it should be one time. So can anyone help me?

```
    I AM SORRY COCO 
    Do you want to stop me?
    I AM SORRY COCO
    Do you want to stop me?
```

```
char stop;
while(1){
    printf("I AM SORRY COCO\n");
    printf("Do you want to stop me?\n");
    scanf("%c",&stop);
    if(stop=='Y'||stop=='y'){
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You type a "N" and hit the return key, don't you? Two keys pressed, two times through the loop.

Comment: So how can i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/34049496/12938627 ?

Comment: Or what was given as duplicate in the close reason?

Comment: no it's not that but why it's duplicate?i don't know

Comment: Can you see the banner at the top of the page, telling you that this question was closed as a duplicate and why, i.e. which other Q/A is considered to ask and answer the same?

Comment: If the two links really do not help then debug your code by inserting a `printf("(%c)\n", stop);` right before your `if`. That should put you on the path to find your problem yourself. And frankly, when you did I bet you will realise that it is what is described in the links....